# Drupal 7 access control with multiple (ALL) vocabularies

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

We are trying to do access control, attaching taxonomy terms to both users and nodes, using 3 vocabularies.

There are 2 great Drupal 7 modules that alow taxonomy access control: Taxonomy Access (based on roles) and TAC Lite (based on users).

But both modules use OR logic when using multiple vocabularies, while we need to match all them.

Is there any alternative or recommended approach to get access control between users and nodes through matching of all associated categories (using taxonomies or not) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Taxonomy Access Control for role based permissions. You can add default selection for each taxonomy vocabulary to denied and then set allow only for specific terms in each vocabulary. With this setting you get to access the content only if each term from each vocabulary is selected. What i haven't managed to accomplish is to allow access if term1,term2 from vocabulary1 match and term3,term4 for vocabulary2 are matched also.